# What are the values of Exchange's XSHADOW and XQDISCARD commands?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, smtp

**Shadow redundancy** is an Exchange-specific feature (beginning with Exchange 2010) that provides a measure of fault tolerance when relaying email messages with SMTP.

The sending Exchange server sends the `EHLO` command.

```
EHLO smtp_sender.example.com
```

The receiving Exchange server may advertise that it supports shadow redundancy with the `XSHADOW` keyword.

```
250-smtp_receiver.example.com
250 XSHADOW
```

The sending Exchange server can then use the `XSHADOW` command, thus informing the receiving Exchange server that it plans to utilize this feature.

```
XSHADOW MGE5N2Q4YjgtNTg4MC00MGYzLWEzNWUtOWE3ZDk4ZGJjMDFlQFVDLUhDMS51bmlib3gubWVA
```

**Question #1** - What is the value of the string that follows the `XSHADOW` command?

If the receiving Exchange server agrees, it replies with a `250` status code.

```
250 tStREZcEVUiXW96O4lqrJA==
```

**Question #2** - What is the value of the string that follows the `250`?

At a later time, the sending Exchange server will use the `XQDISCARD` command to query the receiving Exchange server to determine if it was successful in relaying the message.

```
XQDISCARD 50
```

**Question #3** - What is the value of the string that follows `XQDISCARD`?

If the receiving Exchange server has successfully relayed the message, then it will reply with a `250` status code.

```
250 845e8916-2efb-444f-b7ea-5e676ddfa6a5
```

**Question #4** - What is the value of the string that follows the `250`?

I've read that it's a unique ID for the message that was relayed, but I don't see where this ID was previously exchanged between the servers.

Comment: +1 for a unique Exchange question with tough to find answers.

Answer (score 0):

I am only able to answer Question#1:
The value after XSHADOW is base64 encoded and contains an unique ID, in your case it was:

0a97d8b8-5880-40f3-a35e-9a7d98dbc01e@UC-HC1.unibox.me@

Comment: Thank you.  And what, exactly, does it uniquely identify?